# How can I get working subtitleeditor in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: subtitle

Subtitleeditor is a great software but undermaintained right now so the version in Ubuntu is suboptimal. How can I make it work as good as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one needs to decide if the version in Ubuntu is not sufficient. If one does not need to work with keyframes and have subtitles displayed in the video in the subtitleeditor's interface, she does not need to do much (just install  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg, see below). I am also told 32bit version works better, but I use 64bit version.

First, we need to get build dependencies of subtitleeditor and remove the version from the repositories, if installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove libsubtitleeditor0 subtitleeditor
sudo apt-get build-dep subtitleeditor gstreamermm subversion
```

As subtitleeditor now uses Gstreamer 1.0, we need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

We also need updated C++ bindings that are not available in 14.04, that is gstreammermm 1.0, so get it from [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gstreamermm/archive/1.0.10.tar.gz).

Install some dependencies and compile and install:

```
sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev libtheora-dev libasound-dev libxv-dev libvisual-0.4-dev libcdparanoia-dev
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Then we need to get the source code of subtitleeditor:

```
svn co svn://svn.gna.org/svn/subtitleeditor/trunk subtitleeditor
cd subtitleeditor
```

Now let's build and install the application and link newly installed libraries:

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```